# Question related to the expression of prime, twin-prime, and Sophie Germain prime counting functions in terms of Mertens function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, mobius-function, twin-primes, dirichlet-convolution

This question assumes the following definitions.

---

**(1)** $\quad\pi(x)==\sum\limits_{p\le x}1\qquad\text{(prime counting function where $p\in P$ is a prime})$

**(2)** $\quad\pi_2(x)==\sum\limits_{p_2\le x}1\qquad\text{(twin-prime counting function where $p_2\in P_2$ is a twin-prime)}$

**(3)** $\quad\pi_{sg}(x)==\sum\limits_{p_{sg}\le x}1\qquad\text{(Sophie Germain prime counting function where }\\$ $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{$p_{sg}\in P_{sg}$ is a Sophie Germain prime)}$

**(4)** $\quad M(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}\mu[n]\qquad\text{(Mertens function)}$

---

I believe the prime counting functions defined in (1) to (3) above can be expressed in terms of Mertens function defined in (4) above as follows where

- $\nu(n)$ is the number of distinct primes $p$ dividing $n$,
- $\nu_2(n)$ is the number of distinct twin-primes $p_2$ dividing $n$, and
- $\nu_{sg}(n)$ is the number of distinct Sophie Germain primes $p_{sg}$ dividing $n$.

---

**(5)** $\quad\pi(x)==\sum\limits_{n\le x}\nu(n)\ M\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$

**(6)** $\quad\pi_2(x)==\sum\limits_{n\le x}\nu_2(n)\ M\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$

**(7)** $\quad\pi_{sg}(x)==\sum\limits_{n\le x}\nu_{sg}(n)\ M\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$

---

Formulas (5) to (7) are related to the following more general conjectured relationship which I've tested on several additional functions over small ranges of $x$.

---

**(8)** $\quad f(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x} a(n)=\sum\limits_{n\le x} b(n)\ M(\frac{x}{n})\,,\quad b(n)=\sum\limits_{k|n} a(n)$

---

**Question**: Can the conjectured relationship illustrated in (8) above be proven which would also imply the correctness of formulas (5) to (7) above?

Comment: Maybe can you express (8) in terms of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, by the properties of generalized convolution, we have

$$
\sum_{n\le x}(f*g)(n)=\sum_{n\le x}f(n)\sum_{m\le x/n}g(m)
$$

As a result

$$
\sum_{n\le x}b(n)M\left(\frac xn\right)=\sum_{n\le x}b(n)\sum_{m\le x/n}\mu(m)=\sum_{n\le x}(b*\mu)(n)
$$

By the definition of $b(n)$ and the associativity and commutativity of Dirichlet convolution, we deduce

$$
(b*\mu)(n)=((1*a)*\mu)(n)=(a*(1*\mu))(n)=a(n)
$$

Accordingly, your conjectured relationship is true.